# JavaScript Jquery function that is triggered on event executes all at once instead of right time

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, event-handling

I made a function that Is made to be trigered when user scrolls on a element on the page. In this case when user scrolls to an id then it fades in. The problem is that  they fade in all at the same time with the first scroll instead of when they reaching  the element That is supposed to allow it to fade in! Please help me make my function work.

Thanks a lot

```
var selected={
   //// Storing selectors
   items:[],
   /// Function that stores items and hides them from the page
   selectFunc: function(select) {
   //// Store selected element    
   selected.items.push(select);
   /// hide selector from the page    
    $(select).hide();    
   }
};
//// Function triggeres on scroll    
$(window).scroll(function() {


   /// loops trough the selected elements
   for(i=0; i<selected.items.length; i++){    
   var currentItem = selected.items[i];

       ///// calculates your position and item position
       var hT = $(currentItem).offset().top,
          hH = $(currentItem).outerHeight(),
          wH = $(window).height(),
          wS = $(this).scrollTop();
                 ////// check if you are in the position
                   if (wS > (hT+hH-wH)){
                   $( currentItem ).fadeIn( 2500 );
                 }
           }
   });    

   //// Using my function to select id about and p element in it.  
selected.selectFunc("#about p");
selected.selectFunc("#about input");
```

Comment: please make a small [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) demo where we can see the issue

Comment: When you debug this, where *specifically* does it fail?  It looks like you're looping through all of the items, is that intended?  When you get the height/offset/etc. values, are they what you expect them to be?  Does the `if` statement behave as you expect?  This is a *great* opportunity to use a debugger.

Comment: In your `for` loop, you are doing an iteration for each element in `selected.items`. How many are there? Two: all `<p>`s, and all `<input>`s. You're not looping through each of them. That's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `for` loop, you are doing an iteration for each element in `selected.items`. What's in there? Two strings: "#about p", and "#about input".
So for each of these selectors, you show them all. You need to get every element separately.

Another problem is that hiding these elements means they are not taking up the space they should on the page, so you might not be able to scroll down. You can solve that by changing their opacity instead of making them `display:none` (what `.hide()` is doing).

Here is your code with some modifications:

```
var selected = {
    //// Storing selectors
    items: [],
    /// Function that stores items and hides them from the page
    selectFunc: function(select) {
        //// Store selected element
        var items = $(select);
        for (var i = 0, l = items.length; i < l; i++) selected.items.push(items[i]);
        /// hide selector from the page    
        items.css('opacity', 0);
    }
};
//// Function triggeres on scroll    
$(window).scroll(function() {
    /// loops trough the selected elements
    for (i = 0; i < selected.items.length; i++) {
        var currentItem = selected.items[i];
        ///// calculates your position and item position
        var hT = $(currentItem).offset().top,
            hH = $(currentItem).outerHeight(),
            wH = $(window).height(),
            wS = $(this).scrollTop();
        ////// check if you are in the position
        if (wS > (hT + hH - wH)) {
            $(currentItem).animate({
                'opacity': 1
            }, 2500);
        }
    }
});

//// Using my function to select id about and p element in it.  
selected.selectFunc("#about p");
selected.selectFunc("#about input");

// Simulating a scroll to show the first elements
$(window).scroll();
```

#### JS Fiddle Demo